# Google Docs - Comments Limits

Tags: google-docs

Are the limits in terms of number, length, and content of a comment on a Google Doc documented anywhere? I have a valid docx file that I've uploaded to Google Drive and when attempting to open it in Google Docs repeatedly get the "File could not open. Try refreshing the page." message. I went through all the documented/generic remediation steps and then started dissecting the document to see if I could find the problem. The root cause appears to be that some of the comments in the docx exceeded the Docs comment length limit of 2,048 characters. Is there a list of these types of gotchas somewhere that I can make sure we reference for future use?